# How do I configure SMTP when using Windows Server 2003 as a mail server?

Tags: windows-server-2003, email, smtp, email-server

I added the "Mail Server" role to my Windows Server 2003 server, which gave me POP3 and SMTP (I really only need SMTP). I need a server on my LAN that clients can use to email out without SSL or a login (I will NOT be allowing any traffic from the Internet; this will NOT be an open relay).

I see how I can configure POP3, but I can't find any settings for SMTP (for example, where to change the port, restrict IP ranges, restrict hosts, etc).

Is it possible to configure anything at all, or is this just a vanilla SMTP server with no settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to configure anything
>   at all

Yes. Open IIS Manager and right click on the SMTP Server and go to "Properties". The SMTP server is configured as part of IIS.